# MySql How to do a Simple Join

Tags: mysql, join

I need to do a SELECT query from a table but only return the results that equal an 'I' in a column from another table?
How is this done?

Something like this but I know my syntax is all wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE ITEM_TYPE = 'I' ON table2
```

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I Googled for "mysql join", this was the top result: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
WHERE t2.item_type = 'I'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON
table1.id = table2.id WHERE item_type = 'I';
```